# Prove the reflection of $H$ on the $\overline{BC}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, solution-verification

Let $H$ be the orthocenter of the triangle $\Delta ABC$ and point $A_1$ be a reflection of $H$. Prove $A_1$ belongs to the circumscribed circle of $ABC$.

My attempt:

Let $AH\perp BC$ and $D\equiv AH\cap BC$ and $E\equiv AB\cap EH$.
$$\implies |HD|=|DA_1|\implies \Delta HA_1C\;\text{is isoceles}$$
$$HD\perp BC\;\land\;BE\perp EH\implies\measuredangle EBC=\measuredangle CHD=\measuredangle HA_1C$$
$\implies$ $\measuredangle EBC=\measuredangle AA_1C$ are inscribed angles of the circumscribed circle.
$\implies A_1$ is on the circumscribed circle.

Picture: [image]

Is this legitimate and is there a more efficient method? How can I improve my proof?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's the most efficient way I see. You just need to say that $A_1$ is on the same side of $AC$ as $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct. If you are familiar with the Euler line and dilation, you can see a dilation between those points (D and  A1) and between N (the nine point center) and O (the circumcenter) from H(the orthocenter).